# How to align horizontally fields in Bootstrap input group with addons for colorpicker in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap to show color picker and a checkbox, related to a color selection. The requirement is to show elements in one line: square with selected color inside first; then checkbox, then label, all elelements of same height in one horizontal line.

```
<div class="form-group input-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Color)
    <div class="input-group" id="color-picker-container" align="left">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i></i></span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Color, new { @class = "form-control", id = "color-picker" })
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsNew, new { id = "is-new" })
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsNew)
   </div>
</div>
```

I get desired layout in Firefox/Chrome, but in IE the picture is distorted: selected color is shown in a rectangular of double height; and to the right of rectangular there is a text box in one line, and underneath it there is a checkbox with label in a second line (both lines combined have same height as rectangular with selected color).

What should be changed in order to make all elements to be in a single line in IE, similar to other browsers?

**UPDATE**: We have a logic to use the latest IE version possible, therefore, IE 11 is used.

Answer (score 0):

May be, this will be useful for others. style = "display:inline" for color picker did the trick, since it is overwriting display:table style, that is used for input-group class.

```
<div class="form-group input-group">
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Color)
<div class="input-group" id="color-picker-container" align="left">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i></i></span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Color, new { @class = "form-control", id = "color-picker", style = "display:inline" })
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsNew, new { id = "is-new" })
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsNew)
```

,